# QML: Make property readonly in derived class

Tags: qt, qml

I'm pretty sure the answer is no, but I thought I should ask anyway.  Can an inherited property be made readonly/constant in a pure QML derived class?

```
// Base.qml
Item {
    property int foo: 42
}

// Derived.qml
Base {
    foo: 99 // Make constant somehow!
}
```

I'm currently tackling this by detecting a change in `foo` and printing an error to the console, but that's hardly a mark of good API...

I have a menu item class which can represent menu entries, submenus, separators, etc.  I need to specialise it's behaviour, but *only* for when it is in submenu mode.  I can change the inheritance tree so I have a subclass for each menu type, but this seems silly as each subclass will only contain a single `readonly` property.  However if there isn't another way, I will have to.

Comment: What do you want to get here? For what you need that? May be just there is another solution for that.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Why not use inherited getter/setters for a private foo?
something like :

```
//Base.qml
Item
{
    QtObject
    {
       id : privateFoo
       property int foo : 42
    }

    function getFoo() {return privateFoo.foo;}
    function setFoo(newFoo) { privateFoo.foo = newFoo; }
}

//derived.qml
Base
{
    function getFoo() {return 99;}
    function setFoo(newFoo) { /*do nothing */ }
}
```

(I haven't tested this code)

Comment: That works nicely, my only concern is that it doesn't solve the problem with a "QML paradigm" i.e. through manipulation of properties.  Having said that property binding still works as expected, so I can't argue too much.

Comment: Yeah it's a shame, the convention for private properties is to prefix their name with `__` eg. `__foo` here, but that doesn't prevent anyone to modify this property. It's just an indication that this property is supposed to be internal only.

Comment: six years on: the tick should taken off from the correct answer because it's wrong. use "readonly property alias foo: base._foo"

Answer (score 5):

You can also transform `foo` as a `readonly alias` to an internal property `_foo` that you will use only for assignment in the derived class:

```
// Base.qml
Item {
    id: base

    readonly property alias foo: base._foo

    property int _foo: 42 // only used for assignment in subclasses
}
```

To be used in another Component:

```
Item {
    Base {
        id: child0
    }

    Base {
        id: child1
        _foo: 99
    }

    Base {
        id: child2
        _foo: child1.foo
    }

    Component.onCompleted: {
        console.log("child0:", child0.foo,"child1:", child1.foo, "child2:", child2.foo)
        child1.foo = 5 // not allowed!
        console.log("child0:", child0.foo,"child1:", child1.foo, "child2:", child2.foo)
    }
}
```

Output:

```
child0: 42 child1: 99 child2: 99
TypeError: Cannot assign to read-only property "foo"
```

Note: of course it is still possible to modify `_foo` later. But if you remember to use it only for assignment, then you have the desired behavior with a readonly `foo` in the derived class.